# Trying to implement cross-fade in loop with SoundManager 2

Tags: javascript, audio, soundmanager2

So I have this app and I need to have a fade in and fade out effect every time I loop my sound so that the transitions run smooth.

I am using SoundManager 2.

UPDATED CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Testing sound");
    soundManager.flashVersion = 9;  
    soundManager.url = '/assets/soundmanager/swf/';  
    soundManager.onready(function(){
        soundManager.createSound({  
            id:"EngineIdle",  
            url:"/assets/sounds/EngineIdle.ogg",  
            stream: true,  
            autoPlay: true,  
            multiShot: false,
            volume: 0,
            onplay:function() {
                var fadingin = setInterval(fadein, 20);
            },
            onfinish:function() {
                clearInterval('fadingout'); //We declared the interval as a variable earlier so we can cancel it
                soundManager.play('EngineIdle');
            }
        });
        var FadeOutTime = 2;
        soundManager.onPosition('EngineIdle', FadeOutTime, function(){var fadingout = setInterval(fadeout, 20)});
    });

    function fadein() {
        var s = soundManager.getSoundById('EngineIdle');//Again, unoptimal
        if (s.volume == 100) {
            clearInterval('fadingin');
            return
        }
        s.setVolume(s.volume + 20);
    }
    function fadeout() {
        var s = soundManager.getSoundById('EngineIdle'); //This is unoptimal to call each time, but you can fix that
            if (s.volume > 0) {
                s.setVolume(s.volume - 20);
            }
    }
});
```

Any idea on how I can get a loop with cross-fading between each transition on the same sound?

Answer (score 4):

That method seems quite clumsy, for a few reasons:

- Using setTimeout in the function each time, instead of setInterval once.
- It seems you call fadeOutSound onfinish, so there's no time to fade out.
- Calling a function from itself.

etc

I'll post some ideas here, from which you could build on. First I'd scrap your method, it's clumsy and unoptimal.

First, the best way to loop is something like:

```
soundManager.createSound({  
        id:"EngineIdle",  
        url:"/assets/sounds/EngineIdle.ogg",  
        stream: true,  
        autoPlay: true,  
        multiShot: false,
        volume: 0,
        onfinish:function() {
            soundManager.play(EngineIdle);
        }
});
```

This gives the nicest loop, with the least clutter.

Then set a listener for your fadeout, something like:

```
soundManager.onPosition('EngineIdle', FadeOutTime, function(){var fadingout = setInterval(fadeout, 20)});
```

Where FadeOutTime is however long before it ends you want it to start fading. You could use `sound.duration - x`, `sound.durationEstimate - x`, or if you know the length of the audio just enter an amount in ms.

NB:`soundManager.onPosition` can be tricky, it must be called after the sound is initialized.

Then we need a fadeout function

```
function fadeout() {
    var s = soundManager.getSoundById('EngineIdle'); //This is unoptimal to call each time, but you can fix that
    if (s.volume > 0) {
        s.setVolume(s.volume - 20);
    }
}
```

So it should now fade out, but we don't want to keep calling `fadeout` forever, do we?

Let's change onfinish when we create the sound:

```
onfinish:function() {
        ClearInterval('fadingout'); //We declared the interval as a variable earlier so we can cancel it
        soundManager.play(EngineIdle);
}
```

Now to fade in as well, when we create the sound add:

```
onplay:function() {
    var fadingin = setInterval(fadein, 20);
}
```

And then

```
function fadein() {
    var s = soundManager.getSoundById('EngineIdle');//Again, unoptimal
    if (s.volume === 100) {
        clearInterval('fadingin');
        return
    }
    s.setvolume(s.volume + 20);
}
```

When play is called on the sound, it will increase the volume, and cancel the timer when it hits 100.

This should help you through. Don't copy this code word for word though, I wrote this while distracted, and as more of a guide. Feel free to ask more if it still doesn't work or yuo don't understand.

Comment: thanks, i will test it out in a few days and let you know how it went

Comment: i updated my code above with your changes. it works a little better but still doesn't have the "smooth" desired effect. can you help out?

Comment: For smoother I'd just have the timing different, so it starts fading out sooner, and fades out slower. If you chuck me the audio file I'll mess around and see if I can get it nicer

Comment: Ok, you can download the sound here https://soundcloud.com/psychok7/engineidle , although i was looking for a more generic approach so that users can upload their own sounds, and they can loop smoothly on a generic algorithm

Comment: I'll test some stuff for ya

Comment: so my friends any news? My boss is going to kill me if i don't get this running.. thanks for the effort

Comment: Yes sorry, got caught up in a couple things. Will work on this right away.

Comment: fine :) . i will be waiting.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I implemented a basic fading loop for Soundmanager audio objects.

```
this.fadeAudio = function(audio_out, audio_in, time, callback) {
        audio_in.setVolume(0); //Ensuring silent incoming audio
        audio_in.play();
        vol_inc = (time / audio_out.volume) * 2;
        loop = setInterval(function(){
            if(audio_out.volume <= 0) {
                audio_out.setPosition(audio_out.duration); // Manually finishing song
                callback();
                clearInterval(loop);
            }
            audio_out.setVolume(audio_out.volume - 2);
            audio_in.setVolume(audio_in.volume + 2);
        }, vol_inc);
    }
```

This will run 50 times with incrementing the audio volume by 2% each time.

`time` is the amount of milliseconds you want the fade to last.